# How can one ask a question well, when it is about a subject they don't know?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am struggling to ask [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/automorphisms-of-the-julia-set) here well.

I have in mind a precise question with an exact answer - The difficultly is not knowing the field (fractals) as an expert I cannot use mathematical symbology so I tried to pin it down with words.

I am not sure if this comes across as lazy (I should hope not as I have put quite a lot of time and effort into trying to answer this myself without success) or what, but I would appreciate any suggestions that will help to improve this question in order.

Comment: 'Symbology' *never* helps makes things precise: symbols are just abbreviations of words.

Comment: Symbology sounds like a made-up subject like from the _Harry Potter_ series.

Comment: *Ding*, the correct answer is "notation".

Comment: Symbology *is* a made up subject! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Langdon

Comment: @muad: Since you have deleted the question you ask about here, do you still wish for this meta-question to remain open?

Comment: The question it pertains to have been deleted by the OP. OP is no longer with us on Math.SE. Closing the question so it would pop back-up to front page.